# accessing forms field to upload file

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

After uploading the image file and proceed with the details like name and description I have taxonomy reference term field and I need to have a control on that field to see if the taxonomy exists or no.
So I was thinking when clicking save button the script should run and return error... However, my problem is to find where is located the save button function.
my perfect solution is to upload an image with taxonomy and each taxonomy term should be linked to one image. 1 to 1 relation.

I have tried file.module, File.inc, Form.inc but useless.
does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very bad pratice to modify core or contrib modules if you doesn't have a drupal expertise.

So , you can use hooks to add/modify elements to a form , in particulary [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)
Test it on submit :

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id){

 if($form_id == 'id_of_my_form'){ // if you don't know it var_dump($form_id) on your page
   $form['#submit'][]  = 'my_custom_submit_callback'; // its your own function executed after core/contrib functions on submit
 }
}

function my_custom_submit_callback($form, &$form_state){

 // test your values
 if($form_state['values']['my_field_name']){
   // Deal with value
 }else{
   form_set_error('my_field_name', "Taxonomy is missing");
 }
}
```

NB : Clear cache registry after first creation of those function

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer i have tried to implement the solution i put this function in the template.php file and i got the form id but after that it's not triggered.

Comment: You have to put it into module , if your module is named `my_custom_module` so the function must be named `my_custom_module_form_alter`

Comment: i dont have a custom module i am using the file upload by drupal. using this path 
yoursite.com//file/add.

Comment: i did add the function in file.module, it is working but not triggered on submit